# Resizing label width depending on the width of its content

Tags: c#, winforms, width, label

I'm working on a code-editor and want to auto-adjust the width of a label as the number increases. For example, for 1-9 (1 digit) there's a specific width. Then when it gets to 10-99 (2 digits), width of label increases. Then again for then 100-999 (3 digits), etc.

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void timer_countline_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateNumberLabel();
}

private void updateNumberLabel()
{
    // we get index of first visible char and number of first visible line
    Point pos = new Point(0, 0);
    int firstIndex = rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
    int firstLine = rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstIndex);

    // now we get index of last visible char and number of last visible line
    pos.X = ClientRectangle.Width;
    pos.Y = ClientRectangle.Height;
    int lastIndex = rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
    int lastLine = rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(lastIndex);

    // this is point position of last visible char, we'll use its Y value for calculating numberLabel size
    pos = rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(lastIndex);

    // finally, renumber label
    numberLabel.Text = "";
    for (int i = firstLine; i <= lastLine + 1; i++)
        numberLabel.Text += i + 1 + "\n";
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney, yeah problem was the label flickers everytime i do that since i use timerevent for that

Comment: @Elegiac `AutoSize` should work OK. There is no better way.

Comment: @Elegiac if you want to make an order column, I think you should add each entry as a `Label`, your `updateNumbeLabel` will make the label flicker if the timer Interval is small. I mean you should change the way you want to display the order column. If you want to keep the current way, you may want to use the `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` methods.

Comment: @KingKing can you pls elaborate it clearly? sorry newbie here .really appreciate for that reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **TextRenderer** for doing what you want. Please check the following code lines *(You should add the code lines to **TextChanged** event of your label)*:

*Please remember that the **AutoSize** property of your controls must set to **False**.*

*This is for changing **Width** of your control to fit with width of its contents.*

```
yourLabelName.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(yourLabelName.Text, yourLabelName.Font).Width;
```

*This is for changing **Height** of your control to fit with height of its contents.*

```
yourLabelName.Height = TextRenderer.MeasureText(yourLabelName.Text, yourLabelName.Font).Height;
```

### Update 1:

For changing your panel *Width* for showing all contents in it horizontally, you can use the followng code line:

```
yourPanelName.Width = yourLabelName.Left + yourLabelName.Width;
```

For changing your panel *Height* for showing all contents in it vartically, you can use the followng code line:

```
yourPanelName.Height = yourLabelName.Top + yourLabelName.Height;
```

### Update 2:

If you are used **SplitContainer control**, you must change the properties of your SplitContainer as follows:

```
FixedPanel = none
IsSplitterFixed = False
```

Then you can use the following lines of code for achieve to what you want:

For changing your **SplitContainer panel *Width*** for showing all contents in it horizontally, you can use the followng code line:

```
int yourLabelNameWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(yourLabelName.Text, yourLabelName.Font).Width;
yourSplitContainerName.SplitterDistance = yourLabelName.Left + yourLabelNameWidth;
yourLabelName.Width = yourLabelName.Left + yourLabelNameWidth;
```

Comment: i got an error with this code sir:  splitContainer1.Panel1.Width = numberLabel.Left + numberLabel.Width; --- not supported, the splitterpanel's width cannot be set explicitly. set the splitterdistance on the splitcontainer instead

Comment: If you check *the last code lines* in **Update 2** section, you will see what you mentioned in ur comment.